# Can a link within an object load a new page?

Tags: html

I want to use an imported HTML file for a nav bar so that I can avoid having to manually update the nav bar for every page when I add new pages. My current method of doing so is this:

```
<object data="nav.html" width="85%"></object>
```

where nav.html contains the data for my nav bar. It displays fine, but if I click a link in the nav bar, it loads the page within the object instead of loading the entire page. This means the entire new page is squished into the size of my nav bar, embedded within the previous page. Is there a way to make it so the link loads an entirely new page instead of just loading within the object?

Comment: @devReb that works, but now all links open in a new tab. Is that avoidable?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `target=_blank` to it.
It works for `href` links like: `<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>`

Comment: that works, but now all links open in a new tab. Is that avoidable? Also sorry I took so long to respond, I'm new to this site and put my response in the wrong place (I think).

Comment: Would it still open in a new tab even if you remove the `target=...`?

Comment: That brings back the original problem, where it only displays within the object.

Comment: Actually, I discovered on w3 schools that if I set target to _parent this solves the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I was not aware of the target attribute.

Comment: No worries. God bless! :)